# Select struct-member dependent on a condition in a macro

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, conditional-operator

I'm a bit new to C, so I'm still learning the ropes. I'm having trouble getting a preprocessor-macro to work the way that I want it to. Here's the situation, I have a struct like this:

```
struct super {
    int data1;
    int data2;
    int condition;
};
```

and I would like to create a macro like this:

```
#define getdata(s) (s.condition ? s.data1 : s.data2)
```

so that I can do things like this:

```
getdata(s) = 4 // stores in data1 if condition, data2, if not.
```

But that's not quite working.

Why doesn't it work, and how could I correct it?

Comment: Wired, but interesting +1. But why *getdata*? Was there something that you wanted to *get* done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it this way (the ternary operator never return an lvalue in C):

```
#define getdata(s) (*((s).condition ? &(s).data1 : &(s).data2)
```

Changes:

- Use of address of on the options, and dereference on the result of the conditional operator.
- Added missing parentheses.

Still, be aware that `s` will be evaluated twice. (You can get around that with an inline-function or implementation-dependent magic.)

```
inline int* getdata(struct super* s) {return s->condition ? &s->data1 : &s->data2;}
#define getdata(s) (*getdata(&s))
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a macro that lets you write an assignment to what looks like a function call is just awful. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you should.

Writing inline functions is much better for that kind of thing than using a macro, and much easier to get perfectly right.

Comment: Yeah, the idea is more for fun/learning than for any serious reason.

Comment: Absolutely. This was also my first reaction. As a comment this is valuable, but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can #define a SETDATA() macro, which will be very similar, and will work:

```
#define SETDATA(s,n) ( s.condition ? s.data1 = n : s.data2 = n )
```

Answer (score 0):

In C, you have to use a pointer through the ternary. Your code would work as-is in C++ (but then, in C++, you can return a reference from a function).

```
#define getdata(s) *((s).condition ? &(s).data1 : &(s).data2)
```

I've added parentheses around the `s`'s, but there's still the multiple evaluation problem.

Comment: My answer was a couple seconds later, but it is more complete.